# What Happens to Snapshot and newly cloned table after hbase table is deleted

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have following query about hbase snapshot:

If I execute below statement in give order :

```
hbase> snapshot 'NS1:table1', 'snap_table1'
hbase> disable 'NS1:table1'
hbase> drop 'NS1:table1'
hbase> clone_snapshot 'snap_table1','NS1:table1'`
```

In this case, Can `"NS1:table1"` still holds the data from the snapshot even after major compaction ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**snapshot 'NS1:table1', 'snap_table1'** : it will create the snapshot. snapshot data will not take additional space till the hfiles it's referencing is changed due to some reasons(major/minor-compactions). if hfile is changed or table is deleted, it will copy the hfiles to snapshot path.

**disable 'NS1:table1'** : disable the table. before deleting the table you need to disable it first.

**drop 'NS1:table1'**  : all table data and associated hfds folders will be removed. the referenced  hfiles of the snapshot is moved to snapshot path.

**clone_snapshot 'snap_table1','NS1:table1'** : it will take data from snapshot path and create a table  with same data as of the old table(data will be availbale till the snapshhot taken time).

**Can "NS1:table1" still holds the data from the snapshot even after major compaction**   :  data will be there even after major compacted.

This answer is based on my experience if any mistakes correct me :)

Thanks & Regards
Rahul

Comment: Thank you, I have performed these operation on my QA environment. Soon it will undergo through either compaction. I was afraid and not having the actual details of asked things, will also update the result at the end for confirmation!

Comment: ok Revan. i already checked it in my r&d cluster before answering. you can accept the answer according to your test case status.